# хочу сделать программу по типу угадай песню, не получается отследить ответ

Tags: python, telebot

названия выбираются рандомно из списка в другом участке кода
правильный находится в переменной 'right', но после нажатия на кнопки c 4-мя вариантами ответа ничего не происходит

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    start_keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    start_70_bt = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рок-музыка 70-х", callback_data="rock_music_70")
    start_80_bt = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рок-музыка 80-х", callback_data="rock_music_80")
    start_keyboard.add(start_70_bt, start_80_bt)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f"Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}, это бот, с которымм ты сможешь сыграть в игру \"Угадай песню\". Для начала вы бери категорию", reply_markup=start_keyboard)

    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data)
    def vibor_kat(callback):
        if callback.data == "rock_music_70":
            var_70 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
            var_1_70 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=var[0], callback_data=var[0])
            var_2_70 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=var[1], callback_data=var[1])
            var_3_70 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=var[2], callback_data=var[2])
            var_4_70 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=var[3], callback_data=var[3])
            var_70.add(var_1_70, var_2_70, var_3_70, var_4_70)
            ans = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Играет: "+right, reply_markup=var_70)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(ans, ff)
    def ff (call):
        if call.data == right:
            bot.send_message(call.chat.id, "right")
        elif call.data != right:
            bot.send_message(call.chat.id, "unright")
bot.polling()
```

Comment: Нажатия на кнопку будут хэндится не в `register_next_step_handler` а в `vibor_kat`  так что содержимое `ff` нужно добавлять в `vibor_kat` (Заменив if на elif) а не в `ff`

Comment: @gord1402 спасибо, помогло